# Add properties to href dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I populate list like this:

```
    menu += "</div><div class='col-xs-6'>"
    menu += "<p class='t06'><a href=" + items[item].Enlace + ">" + items[item].Title + "</a></p>";
```

That I want to do is when my `items[item].Title == "CONTACTO"` add to `<a href="">` modal properties like `data-toggle=modal`

I try something like this with jQuery but it isn´t works

```
  if(items[item].Title == "CONTACTO"){
  $("a").attr("href", "data-toggle='modal'")        
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead 
`$("a").attr("href","''").attr("data-toggle","'modal'");`